# Edit a cell value for a column based on other column values using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

On clicking the "Command button1", I want to edit all the cells of highlighted column, for all rows having value in the "Type" column as "Test Point". The value to be set in cells need to be taken from other two columns from respective row as a substring and combining them with "_". I have created the base code, I am stuck at breaking into substring and setting the value to respective cells

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to split your string? How does the input an desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all values in columns D & E are of equal length, you can try this code :

```
Sub test()
Range("B6", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Select

For Each mycell In Selection
    If mycell.Value = "Test Point" Then
       mycell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[1],11,8) &""_"" & MID(RC[2],14,2)"
    End If
Next mycell

End Sub
```

Comment: As of now the length of values are equal but what if I want to make it generic. Column D will contain eight-digit number any how in each case with "-" at start and end and column E will have equal length for all values. thanks for the answer.